# Click Tracking in FXM Sitecore

Tags: fxm

There are many ways to track the user clicks in the Sitecore website using FXM. But is there any method to track the same on Sitecore Pages? Because for FXM, we can only add an external non-Sitecore web pages.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about FXM in nature and is asked in a manner that could potentially be broadly answered.  Please consider reframing the question, adding depth, screenshots, of the question, and tag appropriately.

Comment: Additionally the question and description differs. It is not a question about tracking the click in FXM but on a Sitecore website. And I agree with @PeteNavarra that answers on how to track clicks on a Sitecore website will be way broader.